# what is concept relation Zero to One and how to implement?

Tags: sql-server, relationship, entity-relationship

I see previous answer but really don't understand about relation zero to one 
and in below picture marked sections that don't  know what is relation.
[image: ER diagram]

Answer (score 1):

The marked connections are part of the same line between Student and Standard, partially covered by the StudentAddress entity box (which may be confusing you).  StandardId is an optional foreign key in Student referencing Standard (Teacher has the same kind of relationship to Standard).

Comment: In your opinion instead this,i can draw directly relation between Student and Standard,what is difference between its ???